# Why does tsc give so cryptic errors when leaking transitive implementation types?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a node module A depending on another node module B, both written in Typescript. Module B returns Promises to A and have chosen bluebird as the Promise implementation. B of course have typings for bluebird.

However, if A doesn't have typings of bluebird (which it probably shouldn't in my case), I get errors like:

```
~/d/p/ensime-vscode ❯❯❯ tsc -p .                                                                                                                                                              ⏎ master ✭ ✱
node_modules/ensime-client/**/file-utils.d.ts(1,26):
 error TS2307: Cannot find module 'bluebird'.
```

It took me a while to realize that this was due to me leaking the concrete Promise type of bluebird. Changing all the public return types to PromiseLike made the errors go away.

My question is, is there a way to detect these earlier on my independent module B? I recall sometimes getting errors when modules leaked types that wasn't public before, but in this case module B built just fine. It's all very blurry to me this thing since I'm very new to Typescript. I guess Typescript is a different beast compared to what I'm used to.

Also, isn't it possible for tsc to emit better error messages for these cases?

Small update:
When I'm "leaking" a type that is locally defined this is caught directly in B:

```
export interface CompletionsResponse extends Typehinted {
  completions: [Completion]
}

interface Completion {
}
```

> [ts] 
>   Property 'completions' of exported interface has or is using private name 'Completion'.
>   interface Completion

I would like to be able to catch this kind of thing directly if I'm exposing something from a dependency like 'bluebird'.Promise as well. It was never my intention to expose 'bluebird' as a transitive dependency, and I honestly don't even know how to do that with typings? So as this builds just fine, what has happened is that 'bluebird' silently became a typings "peer dependency" in npm toungue.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by leaking types?

Comment: Just that which I'm describing in the full text. I'm leaking Promise from bluebird and get these errors from a dependee that doesn't have typings for bluebird.Promise. In leaking I mean, it wasn't intentional - I should have typed the public API:s to PromiseLike/Thenable from the beginning, but I think I need a better way to catch this that these tsc compile errors on the dependee.

Comment: Correct me if I'm understanding it wrong: you have a module A, that depends on module B, that via module B Promise types gets. Eg. because the B declaration file specifies that `B.awesomeFunction()` returns a (Bluebird) Promise? If that's the case, did you make sure module B is handling its type dependencies correctly?

Comment: This is basically what I'm asking about - how do I make sure that B is "handling its type dependencies correctly"? B builds fine but exposes types that are not transitive.

Answer (score 1):

If a package has a type dependency on another module, this dependency should be included in the package's `typings.json`, with `typings install bluebird --save`.

Your type declaration of module B should look something like this [type declaration for `redux-persist`](https://github.com/pellejacobs/typed-redux-persist) (but then inside your actual project). It [depends on `redux` for several types](https://github.com/pellejacobs/typed-redux-persist/blob/master/index.d.ts#L3). Therefore, there is a [dependency listed in the `typings.json`](https://github.com/pellejacobs/typed-redux-persist/blob/master/typings.json#L10).

Concerning typescript error messages, they're kind of a pain. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Oh, well, I guess I'm doing something very wrong then. I haven't published typings for my module B separately, but together with that module. Module B lists bluebird in its typings.json, but module A doesn't even have a typings.json. It's a vscode extension…

Comment: Also, I wouldn't actually WANT the typings of bluebird to be exposed to module A so I don't think this is the answer to my question. Your example looks just like my module 'B' here: https://github.com/ensime/ensime-node/blob/master/typings.json#L4

Comment: Also, doing typings install in module 'A' doesn't help. Same problem.

Comment: I completely missed the ball, what I wrote does not seem to make a lot of sense. I installed your package, but I can't make it use the proper file declarations. It might be something concerning your gulp configuration, not using the external declaration files.

Comment: If I get time, I might setup a super minimal repro case on github and re-iterate this question.